# What is IdentityInterface in Magento2

Tags: magento2, model, magento-2.0, interface

I see that a lot of the models in Magento 2 implement `Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface`.
This interface has a single method called `getIdentities`
The implementations of the method usually return `return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];`.

[An example can be found here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/Page.php#L126)
What is this used for?

Comment: I don't really know if that is used but the class is present in the `dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Legacy/_files/obsolete_classes.php` file so maybe it is intended to be removed later.

Comment: Judging by the class comment it is used for cache and make a unique entity ID and used in ESI headers `vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Controller/Block/Esi.php` line 28

Comment: @MatthéoGeoffray yes you're right but the `getIdentities` method is called on a block class in this case, the OP is asking about the models classes

Comment: Oh yes right my bad ;)

Comment: @MatthéoGeoffray. I think you are right. You might want to put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Marius OK I post it as an answer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From what I understood, this is kind of the equivalence of the `getCacheTags` method of Magento 1.

The `getIdentities` from model classes is then used in every block class referencing this model.

Ok let's take the `/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category.php`:

```
public function getIdentities()
{
    $identities = [
        self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId(),
    ];
    if ($this->hasDataChanges() || $this->isDeleted()) {
        $identities[] = Product::CACHE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_TAG . '_' . $this->getId();
    }
    return $identities;
}
```

This method is then referenced in `/Magento/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php`:

```
public function getIdentities()
{
    return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getIdentities();
}
```

In M2, you now have to declare the cache tag with the `getIdentities` method at the model level, then you can use it in blocks referencing those models.

If you check every block implementing the `getIdentities` method, they all reference a corresponding model `getIdentities` method or a corresponding model cache tag such as `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG`

Then those block `getIdentities` methods are used in Varnish for caching reasons as mentioned by Matthéo to set the `X-Magento-Tags` header.

This header is then used in `Magento/Framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php` in the `process()` method to save the cache:

```
$tagsHeader = $response->getHeader('X-Magento-Tags');
$tags = $tagsHeader ? explode(',', $tagsHeader->getFieldValue()) : [];

$response->clearHeader('Set-Cookie');
$response->clearHeader('X-Magento-Tags');
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header_remove('Set-Cookie');
}
$this->cache->save(serialize($response), $this->identifier->getValue(), $tags, $maxAge);
```

Comment: Be careful - identities are just for the full page cache. For the block cache you still need to implement cache_tags and cache_lifetime! It's an addition, not a replacement.

Comment: I wanted to keep FPC in a page with a dynamic block so I had to implement getIdentities in the block, but the model (Slider in my case) depends also on changes in child Model (Banners), should I add both in the identities array ? or the child change means only the parent is needed ? thank you @RobertEgginton

Comment: @RobertEgginton I used CACHE_TAG using getIdentities() in Model and due to this my extension is failed in Varnish PageCache Test, Here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1rzivjt  Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 7):

Judging by the class `Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface` comment it is used for cache and make a unique entity ID that is used in Varnish ESI headers in `vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Controller/Block/Esi.php`line 28.

```
if ($blockInstance instanceof \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface) {
   $response->setHeader('X-Magento-Tags', implode(',', $blockInstance->getIdentities()));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The  IdentityInterface  will  force  Model  class  to  define  the  ​getIdentities()  method which  will return a unique id for the model. You must only use this interface if your model required cache refresh after database operation and render information to the frontend page.

Comment: Thank you. If you could link to the place in the documentation or other good source, then this would be the most useful answer on this page.